# How to delete a row in the table when I click on a button? Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML from with table and button:

```
<div>
                <h1>Info</h1>
                <form>
                    <table id="t">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>index</th>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>job</th>
                            <th>date</th>
                            <th>department</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Alex</td>
                            <td>Hacker</td>
                            <td>100000000000000000</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow()">
                </form>
        </div>
```

I want to remove rows, which have establishes checkbox. Delete should be at the click of a button.

Javascript function that should delete:

```
function deleteRow() {
    let table = document.getElementById('t')
    let boxs = table.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++){
        if(boxs[i] == true) {
            table.deleteRow((boxs[i].parentNode.parentNode).rowIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

I debugged this code, the size of the array defined correctly, but doesn't enter to condition.

Comment: I tried to keep your code. please see my answer. then you will get why your if statement is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code you don't need to change much.
You need to change if statement like below.

**From**

> if(boxs[i] == true) {
>
> }

**To**

> if(boxs[i].checked == true) {
>
> }

Because box[i] is object. 
So If you want to get the check status you need to call boxs[i].checked. This will give you true/false.

```js
function deleteRow() {

    let table = document.getElementById('t')
    let boxs = table.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++){
        if(boxs[i].checked == true) {
         table.deleteRow((boxs[i].parentNode.parentNode).rowIndex)
        }
    }
   return false;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Info</h1>
    <form onsubmit="return deleteRow()">
        <table id="t">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>index</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>job</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>department</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Alex</td>
                <td>Hacker</td>
                <td>100000000000000000</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="delete">
    </form>
</div>
```